# Word for be in sync with or matching with?

Tags: single-word-requests

> A thermostat set-point change that is `_____` with the saved schedule has no effect because, the set-point would have been changed anyway.

(The set-points are changed precisely at the same time and to the same value as the saved schedule).

Comment: Why is "in sync with" not the right answer?

Comment: Or "synchronized with"? "Sync" is a colloquial abbreviation, it's true, and so informal, but usable in most contexts.

Comment: Hmm, true, but felt like it sounds too technical. Looking for more colloquial words and synonyms.

Comment: A set point change that ***duplicates*** the existing schedule...

Comment: Is equal to? (more chars)

Comment: It may be a semantic nit-pick but why are you trying to make the system more complicated?  If all manual changes take precedence over saved schedule changes then you don’t need to test whether a manual set-point change duplicates a saved schedule change and only execute it if it does not- you simply always execute the manual set-point change.  Your documentation then becomes: “Manual thermostat set-point changes  are always executed.” if it so happens that the manual change duplicates the saved schedule then it doesn’t matter- the user gets the result they intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idiomatically, [in unison](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unison?s=t) will work:

> in unison, in perfect accord; corresponding exactly

This has a slightly more technical ring than "in harmony" or "in concert", which seems appropriate in the context.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for the verb 'accord':

"A thermostat set-point change that **accords** with the saved schedule..."

Answer (score 0):

How about "that corresponds with"...? To me that sounds less technical but is technically correct and less awkward than "accord" in this context.

Answer (score 0):

If the schedule contains "set-points", you may say:

> A thermostat set-point change that **matches with** the saved schedule ...

or, if the schedule contains "set-point changes":

> A thermostat set-point change that is **recorded in** the saved schedule ...

Answer (score 0):

I think "Consistent with" would work.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer could be flagged automatically for its length and content. It is not encouraged to post an answer without any research/reference/link that can support it. Please edit your answer after taking the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visiting our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the word ***congruent***.

> (adjective)
>
> 1.
>   in agreement or harmony.
>   "the rules may not be congruent with the requirements of the law"
>   2.
>   GEOMETRY
>   (of figures) identical in form; coinciding exactly when superimposed.